# How do I build the Android SDK source to get Android.jar

Tags: android, android-source

I'm not an expert on Android but I need to Android-SDK byte-code to conduct some experiments.

I compiled Androids source but amazingly it outputs the same SDK which basically contains lame stubs that throw exceptions.

As you may know android.jar that is included in developers package contains stubs and all methods in all classes just throw new RuntimeException("stub"); The purpose of this SDK is only to allow developers to build against android.jar in Eclipse and execute their programs on devices/emulators where the actual SDK is located.

I have separated the java files from Android's source for the SDK but I had no success compiling them. I was wondering if there is a way to do so or to extract them from devices. My final goal is to sort of run Android apps on regular JVM versus running them on emulator or Dalvik.

Answer (score 0):

you can't run android.jar code on the JVM. It's just as you said in your question, you will get a runtime exception if you do. This is by design so that you get all of the syntax and re-factoring tools support from popular java IDE's such as eclipse.

Comment: I know but there should be a way to either compile the source or to extract the actual .class files from a device or an emulator.

Comment: you're not understanding me. The fact that the android.jar exists is solely for Java IDE support.

Comment: I know that. And that's why I have to compile the source code.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz I think OP wants to compile the OS into a ROM like state so he can try to reflect upon it.

Comment: At the top level the source code looks like it can be compiled and ran like you want. But at the lower levels there is a JNI bridge to C++ that runs on Android. So, even if you were able to compile and link all of that, it still will only run on an Android.

Answer (score 0):

android.jar is only for Eclipse as told. 
if we do some changes in Framework and try to use the same build android.jar file it will compile fine. but it will have run-time errors as you need to update the system.img which has all the run-time lib and jar files. please replace the system.img from your costume build. it will work.